# LAN router isolation

Tags: router, lan

I am setting up a large home network for a variety of devices some of which cannot be 100% trusted to behave nicely.

I want to only allow the devices to access the internet.  Very few if any of the devices should be able to access each other.

What kind of router should I be looking for?

(I am talking about a *wired* ethernet network, not *WiFi*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a switch that supports VLAN tagging. VLAN ensures L2 isolation between your devices, so they can't communicate with each other.

TP-link ones are pretty cheap. I use the TL-SG108E at home. The link below shows you how to setup VLAN tagging on a TP-link switch. Try port-based VLAN.

http://www.tp-link.com/us/faq-788.html

Put the devices that should be able to access each other on the same VLAN.

The remaining devices that should only access the Internet should be on an individual VLAN.

The switch port that is connected to the router should be tagged with all the VLAN ids deployed as each device should be able to access the Internet.

Comment: Are you affiliated/associated with TP-Link? If you are, you must say so.

Comment: I am not related to TP-Link. I am just a consumer who is satisfied with his US$37 TL-SG108E switch.

Comment: Zyxels also support VLANs and are cheap and durable.